# BusyBox tar: append workaround given limited disk space?

Tags: linux, bash, tar, busybox

I'm on a Linux system with limited resources and BusyBox -- this version of tar does not support --append, -r. Is there a workaround that will allow me to [1] append files from directory B to an existing tar of files from directory A after [2] making the B-files appear to have come from directory A? (Later, when someone extracts the files, they should all end up in the same directory A.)

Situation: I have a list of files that I want to tar, but I must process some of these files first. The files might be used by other processes so I don't want to edit them in-place. I want to be conservative when using disk space so my script only copies those files which it needs to change (vs copying them all and then processing some and finally archiving them all with tar -- if I copied them all I might run into disk space issues).

This means the files I want to archive end up in two separate locations. But I want the resulting tar file to appear as if they were all in the same location. Near the end of my script, I end up with two text files listing the A and B files by name.

I think this is straightforward with a full-blown version of tar, but I have to work with the BusyBox version (usage below). Thanks in advance for any ideas!

```
Usage: tar -[cxtzjaZmvO] [-X FILE] [-f TARFILE] [-C DIR] [FILE]...

Create, extract, or list files from a tar file

Operation:
   c    Create
   x    Extract
   t    List
Options:
   f    Name of TARFILE ('-' for stdin/out)
   C    Change to DIR before operation
   v    Verbose
   z    (De)compress using gzip
   j    (De)compress using bzip2
   a    (De)compress using lzma
   Z    (De)compress using compress
   O    Extract to stdout
   h    Follow symlinks
   m    Don't restore mtime
   exclude  File to exclude
   X    File with names to exclude
   T    File with names to include
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, you just need to append a `tar` repository containing the additional files to the end of the `tar` file. It is only slightly more difficult than that.

A tar file consists of any number of repetitions of `header + file`. The header is always a single 512-byte block, and the file is padded to a multiple of 512 bytes, so you can think of these units as being a variable number of 512-byte blocks. Each block is independent; it's header starts with the full pathname to the file. So there is no requirement that files in a directory be tarred together.

There is one complication. At the end of the tar file, there are at least two 512-byte blocks completely filled with 0s. When tar is reading a tar file, it will ignore a single zero-filled header, but the second one will cause it to stop reading the file. If it hits EOF, it will complain, so the terminating empty headers are required.

There might be more than two headers, because tar actually writes in blocks which are a multiple of 512 bytes. Gnu tar, for example, by default writes in multiples of 20 512-byte chunks, so the smallest tar file is normally 10240 bytes.

In order to append new data, you need to first truncate the existing file to eliminate the empty blocks.

I believe that if the tar file was produced by busybox, there will only be two empty blocks, but I haven't inspected the code. That would be easy; you only need to truncate the last 1024 bytes of the file before appending the additional files.

For general tar files, it is trickier. If you knew that the files themselves didn't have NUL bytes in them (i.e. they were all simple text files), you could remove empty headers until you found a block with a non-0 byte in it, which wouldn't be too difficult.

What I would do is:

1. Truncate the last 1024 bytes of the tar file.
2. Remember the current size of the tar file.
3. Append a test tar file consisting of the tar of a file with a simple short message
4. Verify that `tar tf` correctly shows the test file
5. Truncate the file back to the remembered length,

   - If the `tar tf` found the test file's name, succeed
   - If the last 512 bytes of the tar file are all 0s, truncate the last 512 bytes of the file, and return to step 2.
   - Otherwise fail

If the above procedure succeeds, you can proceed to append the tar repository with the new files.

I don't know if you have a trunc command. If not, you can use `dd` copy a file over top of an old file at a specified offset (see the `seek=` option). `dd` will truncate the file automatically at the end of the copy. You can also use `dd` to read a 512 byte block (see the `skip` and `count` options).

Comment: Will that procedure work for all valid tar files regardless of their contents?

Comment: @user1011471: I don't see why not.

Comment: The reason I ask is because some of the files themselves are .gz files. You wrote "If you knew that the files themselves didn't have NUL bytes in them (i.e. they were all simple text files), you could remove empty headers until you found a block with a non-0 byte in it" ... and ... "If the last 512 bytes of the tar file are all 0s" ...

Comment: Ah but a gzipped file probably isn't going to contain an entire block of 512 zeros, being compressed.

Comment: @user1011471: The algorithm I present doesn't depend on the files not having nul bytes. The simpler algorithm of just truncating blocks until you find one which is not all zero does depend on this feature, and that's why I rejected it.

Comment: There's something I have yet to understand: What is the reason in `5b` for checking if the last 512 bytes has all 0s? Why is it not sufficient to discard as few 512-blocks as possible for `tar tf` to succeed? (I'm also not sure how to write the code to perform that check :-P)

Comment: @user1011471: Just in case :) It's probably not necessary, but sometimes it's useful to know when things you thought were the case are not (particularly with busybox, which sometimes plays a bit fast and loose).

Comment: `tar -tvf <tar-file> | awk '{N += $3 + (512 - ($3 % 512)) + 512}END{print N}'` will find the number of bytes from beginning of the tar file (`head -c`), assuming `tar -tvf` output format returns file size in third field; files with trailing zero bytes should be accounted for.

Comment: In GNU AWK modulo operator can also be replaced with potentially faster bitwise AND (using `$3 & 511` instead of `$3 % 512`), but maintaining compatibility with busybox, expression can still be compacted to just

`tar -tvf <tar-file> | awk '{N+=$3+1024-$3%512}END{print N}'`.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to cut the last 1024 bytes and concatenate a new tar after it. In order to append a tar to an existing tar file, they must be uncompressed.

For files like:

```
$ find a b
a
a/file1
b
b/file2
```

You can:

```
$ tar -C a -czvf a.tar.gz .
$ gunzip -c a.tar.gz | { head -c -$((512*2)); tar -C b -c .; } | gzip > a+b.tar.gz
```

With the result:

```
$ tar -tzvf a+b.tar.gz 
drwxr-xr-x 0/0         0 2018-04-20 16:11:00 ./
-rw-r--r-- 0/0         0 2018-04-20 16:11:00 ./file1
drwxr-xr-x 0/0         0 2018-04-20 16:11:07 ./
-rw-r--r-- 0/0         0 2018-04-20 16:11:07 ./file2
```

Or you can create both tar in the same command:

```
$ tar -C a -c . | { head -c -$((512*2)); tar -C b -c .; } | gzip > a+b.tar.gz
```

Although this is for tar generated by busybox tar. As mentioned in previous answer, GNU tar add multiple of 20 blocks. You need to force the number of blocks to be 1 (--blocking-factor=1) in order to know in advance how many blocks to cut:

```
 $ tar --blocking-factor=1 -C a -c . | { head -c -$((512*2)); tar -C b -c .; } | gzip | tar --blocking-factor=1 -tzv
```

Anyway, GNU tar do have --append. The last --blocking-factor=1 is only needed if you indent do append the resulting tar again.